# How to compare two pandas dataframe and result add as row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframe like 1st Datafarme

```
index  a   b   c   d
  0    4   5   3   2
  1    1   10  21  34
  2    3   32  1   45
  3    56  42  42  23
```

2nd Dataframe

```
 index   a  b  c  d
  LL    2  2  2  1
  UL    42 2  1  8
```

I want excepted output like this.

```
 index    a       b           c           d
  LL      2       2           2           1
  UL      42      2           1           8
  Result [1,56] [5,10,32,42] [3,21,1,42] [34,45,23]
```

Comment: Why the line `result` has different lenght lists?

Answer (score 0):

i have done like this

```
 cond = (dd1<dd2.loc['LL',:]) | (dd1>dd2.loc['UL',:])

 dd3=dd2.append(dd1[cond].apply(lambda x : list(x.dropna())),ignore_index=True)
```